# Trigger Pusher event from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [Pusher](http://pusher.com/docs/quickstart) for real-time page update for my static JavaScript app. when i tried to invoke trigger event its not responding anythin. here is my code

```
var pusher = new Pusher('5f5ebdf0612fbafff349');  
var myChannel = pusher.subscribe('channel_1')  
myChannel.trigger("say_hello", {'name':"Jai", 'age':22});
```

Comment: You may want to remove your Pusher API key from the posted code, just FYI :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on error messages or debug output? Your code looks okay. Can you see the event in the Pusher web console?

Answer (score 6):

You can only trigger events Using JS ( It is not advisable until you clearly know what you are doing) once you have a subscription successfully registered with Pusher for Client Side Triggers.

It is important that you apply additional care when binding to client- prefixed events, since these originate from other users (client side), and could be subject to tampering by a malicious user of your site (any one can modify and execute your JS).

Read this for getting acces to client side event triggering:
http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#trigger-events